# Trouble in installing requirements.txt file on windows while installing manim

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt, manim

This is my file how do i install it using command prompt?

```
argparse
colour
numpy
Pillow
scipy
sympy
tqdm
mapbox-earcut
matplotlib
moderngl
moderngl_window
pydub
pyyaml
screeninfo
pyreadline; sys_platform == 'win32'
validators
ipython
PyOpenGL
manimpango>=0.2.0,<0.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go into the directory of requirements.txt, and type:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

OR

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

which would install all the packages inside the file.